# How Do I Write A Regular Expression For A Name?

Tags: regex

How do I write a regular expression for a name?

I would like it to validate The following examples:

> Albert Einstein
>
> ALBERT EINSTEIN
>
> ALBert EINstein
>
> alberT einstIN
>
> Ale'rt E'i'n't'e'in

These should all be considered valid.

This is what I have so far, but it fails:

```
-(BOOL) validateName: (NSString *) name{
    
    NSString *nameRegex = @"(?:[A-Z]+[a-z' '])"; 
    NSPredicate *nameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegex];
    return [nameTest evaluateWithObject:name];
}
```

Can anyone suggest an improvement?

Comment: You can't "validate" an actual name with a simple regular expression, you can only validate what you decide is acceptable. There are plently of names with more than two words, unusual characters, perhaps even a number! Take for example: `Billy-Bob James O'Brien Ⅻ`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right Regular Expression is this one: 
^[a-zA-Z ]+$

This Regular Expression recognize alle the word containing lower/capital letters separated by spaces.

You can test your Regular Expression [here](http://www.nvcc.edu/home/drodgers/ceu/resources/test_regexp.asp)

Comment: I want to add one more Giuseppe it can take This example Albe'rt E'i'n't'e'in

Comment: This regular expression will help me lot too

Comment: If you want to add ' in the range of valid characters just add this inside the square braces. i.e. : ^[a-zA-Z ']+$

Comment: You will need more than that to make this actually useful for a real person's name. -1 For claiming this is the "right" regex (there really isn't one).

Comment: I think the question was clear, He want to recognize a name providing a validation list. My answer is correct: the regular expression recognize the names present in his list and I also provide a link in order to test this result.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your expression in

> (?ismwx-ismwx: ... )
>
> Flag settings. Evaluate the parenthesized expression with the
>   specified flags enabled or -disabled. The flags are defined in “Flag
>   Options.”

Case insensitive flag is i.

Or you can use

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"albert einstein" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

But you'll need to specify the context where names appear to have something general...

Answer (score 0):

`^[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+)*$`

It works with

`Albert, Albert Einstein, Edison Arantes do Nascimento aka Pele

If you need exactly 2 words use:

`^[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+$`